# Custom Corr function in Polars

Tags: dataframe, performance, correlation, python-polars

I would like to use a custom function with the the Polars' df.corr function the same way I use Pandas' df.corr. I realize that custom functions will not perform as well in Polars as the Spearman and Pearson built-in functions, but having a workaround may be faster than the pandas implementation, especially for large datasets. function for example:

```
###Pandas

from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import pearsonr

def pearsonr_pval(x,y):
    return pearsonr(x,y)[1]

df=pd.DataFrame(load_iris()['data'],columns=load_iris()['feature_names'])
r_val=df.corr()
p_val=df.corr(method=pearsonr_pval)    #<-----this line works fine
```

But I want to do something like this

```
###Polars

from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
import polars as pl
from scipy.stats import pearsonr

def pearsonr_pval(x,y):
    return pearsonr(x,y)[1]

df=pl.DataFrame(load_iris()['data'],columns=load_iris()['feature_names'])
r_val=df.corr()
p_val=df.corr(method=pearsonr_pval)   #<----This line will not work because corr does not support custon functions
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like polars `.corr()` is hardcoded to call `np.corrcoef`:

https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/blob/master/py-polars/polars/dataframe/frame.py#L8114

I think you would just have to call `pearsonr` directly in your custom function - something like:

```
def pearsonr_pval(df):
   names = pl.DataFrame(df.columns, schema=["name"])
   return names.hstack(
      pl.DataFrame(
         ([pearsonr(x, y)[1] for x in df] for y in df),
         schema = df.columns
      )
   )
```

```
>>> pearsonr_pval(df)
shape: (4, 5)
┌───────────────────┬───────────────────┬──────────────────┬───────────────────┬──────────────────┐
│ name              ┆ sepal length (cm) ┆ sepal width (cm) ┆ petal length (cm) ┆ petal width (cm) │
│ ---               ┆ ---               ┆ ---              ┆ ---               ┆ ---              │
│ str               ┆ f64               ┆ f64              ┆ f64               ┆ f64              │
╞═══════════════════╪═══════════════════╪══════════════════╪═══════════════════╪══════════════════╡
│ sepal length (cm) ┆ 0.0               ┆ 0.151898         ┆ 1.0387e-47        ┆ 2.3255e-37       │
│ sepal width (cm)  ┆ 0.151898          ┆ 0.0              ┆ 4.5133e-8         ┆ 0.000004         │
│ petal length (cm) ┆ 1.0387e-47        ┆ 4.5133e-8        ┆ 0.0               ┆ 4.6750e-86       │
│ petal width (cm)  ┆ 2.3255e-37        ┆ 0.000004         ┆ 4.6750e-86        ┆ 0.0              │
└───────────────────┴───────────────────┴──────────────────┴───────────────────┴──────────────────┘
```

Although it looks like the pandas version returns `1.0` instead when the value is `0.0`?

Comment: Thanks! This is helpful :),

Unfortunately, it is still faster to convert the Polars frame to Pandas, apply the function in Pandas, then go back go Polars. It also looks like the np.corrcoef is doing all the hard work, so if np just came out with a way to do the corrpval in addition to corrcoef that would work better.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in parallel (by virtue of each column combination having it's own expression) if you create the combination of columns in a list of expressions.

Start off creating the helper function which just returns a float:

```
def pearsonr_pval(x,y):
    return pearsonr(x,y).pvalue
```

Then create a list of expressions using that function with `pl.reduce` to create a 1 row dataframe with all the p-values.

```
exprs=[]
for n1, x in enumerate(df.columns):
    for y in df.columns[n1:]:
        exprs.append(
            pl.reduce(pearsonr_pval, 
                        [pl.col(x), pl.col(y)]).alias(f"{x}_____{y}"))
```

If you're happy with a 1 row data frame of that sort then you can just leave it at

```
df.select(exprs)
shape: (1, 10)
┌────────────┬────────────┬────────────┬────────────┬─────┬────────────┬────────────┬────────────┬────────────┐
│ sepal      ┆ sepal      ┆ sepal      ┆ sepal      ┆ ... ┆ sepal      ┆ petal      ┆ petal      ┆ petal      │
│ length (cm ┆ length (cm ┆ length (cm ┆ length (cm ┆     ┆ width (cm) ┆ length (cm ┆ length (cm ┆ width (cm) │
│ )_____sepa ┆ )_____sepa ┆ )_____peta ┆ )_____peta ┆     ┆ _____petal ┆ )_____peta ┆ )_____peta ┆ _____petal │
│ l leng...  ┆ l widt...  ┆ l leng...  ┆ l widt...  ┆     ┆ width...   ┆ l leng...  ┆ l widt...  ┆ width...   │
│ ---        ┆ ---        ┆ ---        ┆ ---        ┆     ┆ ---        ┆ ---        ┆ ---        ┆ ---        │
│ f64        ┆ f64        ┆ f64        ┆ f64        ┆     ┆ f64        ┆ f64        ┆ f64        ┆ f64        │
╞════════════╪════════════╪════════════╪════════════╪═════╪════════════╪════════════╪════════════╪════════════╡
│ 0.0        ┆ 0.151898   ┆ 1.0387e-47 ┆ 2.3255e-37 ┆ ... ┆ 0.000004   ┆ 0.0        ┆ 4.6750e-86 ┆ 0.0        │
└────────────┴────────────┴────────────┴────────────┴─────┴────────────┴────────────┴────────────┴────────────┘
```

If you want it in the form of a matrix then you can do a melt/split/pivot

```
    (
    df
        .select(exprs)
        .melt()
        .with_columns(pl.col('variable').str.split("_____")) 
        .select(
            pl.col('variable').list.first().alias('name'), 
            pl.col('variable').list.last().alias('c2'), 
            pl.col('value'))
        .pivot('value', 'name', 'c2')
)
shape: (4, 5)
┌───────────────────┬───────────────────┬──────────────────┬───────────────────┬──────────────────┐
│ name              ┆ sepal length (cm) ┆ sepal width (cm) ┆ petal length (cm) ┆ petal width (cm) │
│ ---               ┆ ---               ┆ ---              ┆ ---               ┆ ---              │
│ str               ┆ f64               ┆ f64              ┆ f64               ┆ f64              │
╞═══════════════════╪═══════════════════╪══════════════════╪═══════════════════╪══════════════════╡
│ sepal length (cm) ┆ 0.0               ┆ 0.151898         ┆ 1.0387e-47        ┆ 2.3255e-37       │
│ sepal width (cm)  ┆ null              ┆ 0.0              ┆ 4.5133e-8         ┆ 0.000004         │
│ petal length (cm) ┆ null              ┆ null             ┆ 0.0               ┆ 4.6750e-86       │
│ petal width (cm)  ┆ null              ┆ null             ┆ null              ┆ 0.0              │
└───────────────────┴───────────────────┴──────────────────┴───────────────────┴──────────────────┘
```

If you want to get rid of the nulls so it's symmetric then you could just take out the `[n1:]` from the `y` for loop but then it does double the work. Alternatively you can save the intermediate step here:

```
tempdf = (
df
    .select(exprs)
    .melt()
    .with_columns(pl.col('variable').str.split("_____"))
    .select(
        pl.col('variable').list.first().alias('name'), 
        pl.col('variable').list.last().alias('c2'), 
        pl.col('value')))
```

then `vstack` that with itself but with the `name` and `c2` columns switched and finally the pivot:

```
(
tempdf
    .vstack(
        tempdf.select(
            pl.col('c2').alias('name'), 
            pl.col('name').alias('c2'), 
            pl.col('value')))
    .pivot('value', 'name', 'c2')
)

shape: (4, 5)
┌───────────────────┬───────────────────┬──────────────────┬───────────────────┬──────────────────┐
│ name              ┆ sepal length (cm) ┆ sepal width (cm) ┆ petal length (cm) ┆ petal width (cm) │
│ ---               ┆ ---               ┆ ---              ┆ ---               ┆ ---              │
│ str               ┆ f64               ┆ f64              ┆ f64               ┆ f64              │
╞═══════════════════╪═══════════════════╪══════════════════╪═══════════════════╪══════════════════╡
│ sepal length (cm) ┆ 0.0               ┆ 0.151898         ┆ 1.0387e-47        ┆ 2.3255e-37       │
│ sepal width (cm)  ┆ 0.151898          ┆ 0.0              ┆ 4.5133e-8         ┆ 0.000004         │
│ petal length (cm) ┆ 1.0387e-47        ┆ 4.5133e-8        ┆ 0.0               ┆ 4.6750e-86       │
│ petal width (cm)  ┆ 2.3255e-37        ┆ 0.000004         ┆ 4.6750e-86        ┆ 0.0              │
└───────────────────┴───────────────────┴──────────────────┴───────────────────┴──────────────────┘
```

***slightly* Alternative approach**
From a performance perspective, there's a reasonable chance that either the `str.split` or `pivot` are going to hurt the most so maybe in the initial expression making loops, instead of aliasing all the new columns by string concating the old names, you just name them an arbitrary `uuid` while saving the x/y in a different df and then join them like this:

```
exprs=[]
indxdf=[]
for n1, x in enumerate(df.columns):
    for y in df.columns[n1:]:
        thiscol=str(uuid.uuid4())
        exprs.append(pl.reduce(pearsonr_pval, [pl.col(x), pl.col(y)]).alias(thiscol))
        indxdf.append({'c1':x, 'c2':y, 'uuid':thiscol})

df.select(exprs).melt(variable_name='uuid') \
    .join(pl.from_dicts(indxdf), on='uuid').drop('uuid')
```

If someone does that with big enough data to find an appreciable performance difference then please let me know.

Comment: it should be pl.col("variable").list instead of pl.col("variable").arr since the latter does not have first or last methods.

Comment: @altunyurt this answer was back before there was a `.list` namespace and only `.arr` that functioned as `.list` does now. I'll edit it.