# how to calculate correlation between ten columns with polars

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-polars

I previously have a large dataframe in pandas and I am having a hard time migrating to Polars.

I used to use the code below to calculate correlation between columns

```
print(df.corr(numeric_only=True).stack().sort_values(ascending=False).loc[lambda x: x < 1])
```

and result is like:

[image]

how am I supposed to achieve same result with Polars?

many thanks.

Comment: Similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75845238/custom-corr-function-in-polars/75858440#75858440

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using `corr()` and `melt()`.

```py
(
    df_pl.corr()
    .with_columns(index = pl.lit(df_pl.columns))
    .melt(id_vars = "index")
    .filter(pl.col('index') != pl.col('variable'))
)

# Output
┌───────┬──────────┬───────────┐
│ index ┆ variable ┆ value     │
│ ---   ┆ ---      ┆ ---       │
│ str   ┆ str      ┆ f64       │
╞═══════╪══════════╪═══════════╡
│ B     ┆ A        ┆ 0.493197  │
│ C     ┆ A        ┆ -0.866325 │
│ D     ┆ A        ┆ -0.493197 │
│ A     ┆ B        ┆ 0.493197  │
│ …     ┆ …        ┆ …         │
│ D     ┆ C        ┆ 0.416025  │
│ A     ┆ D        ┆ -0.493197 │
│ B     ┆ D        ┆ -1.0      │
│ C     ┆ D        ┆ 0.416025  │
└───────┴──────────┴───────────┘
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the (few) areas where Pandas indexing makes it easier to work with data vs Polars. Still, not that difficult. One solution, broken down in steps:

```py
import numpy as np
import polars as pl

# create a dataframe with 20 rows (time dimension) and 10 columns (items)
df = pl.DataFrame(np.random.rand(20,10))

# compute a wide dataframe where column names are joined together using the "|", transform into long format
long = df.select([pl.corr(pl.all(),pl.col(c)).suffix("|" + c) for c in df.columns]).melt()
long
shape: (100, 2)
┌───────────────────┬───────────┐
│ variable          ┆ value     │
│ ---               ┆ ---       │
│ str               ┆ f64       │
╞═══════════════════╪═══════════╡
│ column_0|column_0 ┆ 1.0       │
│ column_1|column_0 ┆ 0.054075  │
│ column_2|column_0 ┆ -0.099094 │
│ column_3|column_0 ┆ -0.415642 │
│ …                 ┆ …         │
│ column_6|column_9 ┆ -0.426739 │
│ column_7|column_9 ┆ 0.347615  │
│ column_8|column_9 ┆ -0.242504 │
│ column_9|column_9 ┆ 1.0       │
└───────────────────┴───────────┘

# make it nice
table = long.select(c1=pl.col("variable").str.split("|").arr.get(0),c2=pl.col("variable").str.split("|").arr.get(1),corr=pl.col("value"))
table
shape: (100, 3)
┌──────────┬──────────┬───────────┐
│ c1       ┆ c2       ┆ corr      │
│ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---       │
│ str      ┆ str      ┆ f64       │
╞══════════╪══════════╪═══════════╡
│ column_0 ┆ column_0 ┆ 1.0       │
│ column_1 ┆ column_0 ┆ 0.054075  │
│ column_2 ┆ column_0 ┆ -0.099094 │
│ column_3 ┆ column_0 ┆ -0.415642 │
│ …        ┆ …        ┆ …         │
│ column_6 ┆ column_9 ┆ -0.426739 │
│ column_7 ┆ column_9 ┆ 0.347615  │
│ column_8 ┆ column_9 ┆ -0.242504 │
│ column_9 ┆ column_9 ┆ 1.0       │
└──────────┴──────────┴───────────┘

# do the filter. Note that due to floating point precision, we round to 6 digits first
table.filter(pl.col("corr").round(6)<1).sort("corr", descending=True)
shape: (90, 3)
┌──────────┬──────────┬───────────┐
│ c1       ┆ c2       ┆ corr      │
│ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---       │
│ str      ┆ str      ┆ f64       │
╞══════════╪══════════╪═══════════╡
│ column_9 ┆ column_3 ┆ 0.389453  │
│ column_3 ┆ column_9 ┆ 0.389453  │
│ column_9 ┆ column_7 ┆ 0.347615  │
│ column_7 ┆ column_9 ┆ 0.347615  │
│ …        ┆ …        ┆ …         │
│ column_9 ┆ column_6 ┆ -0.426739 │
│ column_6 ┆ column_9 ┆ -0.426739 │
│ column_6 ┆ column_4 ┆ -0.44842  │
│ column_4 ┆ column_6 ┆ -0.44842  │
└──────────┴──────────┴───────────┘
```

If the point of the filter `corr < 1` is to filter out the diagonal of the correlation matrix, you can modify the filter expression to be

```py
pl.col("c1") != pl.col("c2")
```

The string concatting is not nice, an alternative way to generate the correlation matrix is to use a struct

```py
df.select([pl.struct(pl.corr(pl.all(),pl.col(c))).alias(c) for c in df.columns]).melt().unnest("value")
```

which generates:

```
shape: (10, 11)
┌──────────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┬───┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┐
│ variable ┆ column_0  ┆ column_1  ┆ column_2  ┆ … ┆ column_6  ┆ column_7  ┆ column_8  ┆ column_9  │
│ ---      ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆   ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---       │
│ str      ┆ f64       ┆ f64       ┆ f64       ┆   ┆ f64       ┆ f64       ┆ f64       ┆ f64       │
╞══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪═══╪═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╡
│ column_0 ┆ 1.0       ┆ 0.054075  ┆ -0.099094 ┆ … ┆ -0.367074 ┆ 0.122707  ┆ 0.00726   ┆ 0.128825  │
│ column_1 ┆ 0.054075  ┆ 1.0       ┆ 0.293945  ┆ … ┆ 0.073397  ┆ -0.010362 ┆ 0.102971  ┆ 0.116059  │
│ column_2 ┆ -0.099094 ┆ 0.293945  ┆ 1.0       ┆ … ┆ 0.288181  ┆ 0.178947  ┆ 0.112046  ┆ -0.282339 │
│ column_3 ┆ -0.415642 ┆ -0.002478 ┆ 0.010465  ┆ … ┆ -0.025915 ┆ 0.170371  ┆ -0.12935  ┆ 0.389453  │
│ …        ┆ …         ┆ …         ┆ …         ┆ … ┆ …         ┆ …         ┆ …         ┆ …         │
│ column_6 ┆ -0.367074 ┆ 0.073397  ┆ 0.288181  ┆ … ┆ 1.0       ┆ -0.190084 ┆ -0.158802 ┆ -0.426739 │
│ column_7 ┆ 0.122707  ┆ -0.010362 ┆ 0.178947  ┆ … ┆ -0.190084 ┆ 1.0       ┆ -0.097163 ┆ 0.347615  │
│ column_8 ┆ 0.00726   ┆ 0.102971  ┆ 0.112046  ┆ … ┆ -0.158802 ┆ -0.097163 ┆ 1.0       ┆ -0.242504 │
│ column_9 ┆ 0.128825  ┆ 0.116059  ┆ -0.282339 ┆ … ┆ -0.426739 ┆ 0.347615  ┆ -0.242504 ┆ 1.0       │
└──────────┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┴───┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┘
```

From there, you can do melt and the same as in the other solution.

Comment: The next answer is easier, forgot about `DataFrame.corr`. Still, you may find the application of `melt` in my answer useful.